# Calling an associative array that's in a class

Tags: php, arrays

Pretty sure there's a simple solution to this that I'm not seeing, but currently trying to create a simple system that checks the user's username and password input before allowing them to proceed. If the checks don't hold up, an error message is displayed indicating what was wrong with their input. I'm attempting this through an associative array like so:

```
  public function check() {
if (strlen($this->_username) < $this->_minimumChars) {
    $this->_error['idlength'] = "Username needs to be longer than $this->_minimumChars characters";
}
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $this->_username)) {
    $this->_error['idformat'] = "Username can only contain letters and numbers";
}
if (strlen($this->_password) < $this->_minimumChars) {
    $this->_error['pwdlength'] = "Password must be longer than $this->_minimumChars characters";
}
if (empty($this->_error)) {
    return $this->_result = true;
} }
```

I have initiated the $_error variable as `protected $_error = array();`

And I'm trying to call the method

```
  public function getError() {
return $this->_error; }
```

By using `$errors = $checker->getError();` where $checker is an instance of the class.
However, when I try using the $errors array it seems there's nothing initiated. I've tried troubleshooting it through using `empty($errors['idlength'])` in a conditional statement and it seems there's no elements inside the array.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: are you sure the username and password are set? Are you sure the check() function is being called? Are you sure the username and password are failing the checks?

Comment: I created a "success" redirect for when the username/password pass the checks, and when I enter a username/password that pass them it correctly executes the corresponding commands. It's only when the username/password fail the checks that the $errors array isn't working properly.

Comment: You could try initializing the $_error property in the constructor, instead of in-line like that, might not matter.

Comment: I would change this line return $this->_result = true; to $this->_result = true; return $this->_result; and see what happens.

Comment: Zzz.. Nevermind, found the solution.. Called the method getError() before calling check(). Thank you though!